# A quote from "The Folded Leaf" By William Maxwell

Tags: quotes

From The Folded Leaf By William Maxwell

When describing Mr. Peters, the author writes:

"Time is probably no more unkind to sporting characters than it is to other people, but physical decay unsustained by respectability is somehow more noticeable."

This quote is quite difficult for me to understand. It says how time is not kind to both kind people and other types of people, but then I get to the second half of the quote and I am lost.

Answer (score 3):

The first part says that time is unkind to people (by which it means causes them to decay physically) and that it is so equally to both "sporting characters" (which he may mean literally,  i.e. those that often play sports, or maybe as a standin for a disreputable activity) and others. In the second part he says that the physical decay is more noticeable when the person is not 'respectable' - the implication being that "sporting characters" are not respectable,  and therefore their decay is more noticeable.

Comment: I suspect *sporting* means *gambling* here? Otherwise, why would "those that often play sports" lack respectability?

Comment: Or perhaps he's a bit of a washed up ladies man?

Comment: "sporting" has many meanings, including engaging in sexual activity. In the OP's quote it means frittering one's life away in disreputable pursuits such as gambling, drinking, womanizing, betting on dog fights or cock fights, constantly borrowing money that is never repaid,  and being on the fringes of the law.  My only source for this is my general knowledge, reinforced by the [OED, sporting](http://www.oed.com/search?searchType=dictionary&q=sporting&_searchBtn=Search).  Use this if you want to!